# Sidekiq Worker takes a really long time to execute after being queued (4 - 6 seconds)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq, newrelic

I have a sidekiq worker that queues around 15 - 20 jobs of a different type of worker.  When I go to New Relic's transaction, each of the workers that are queued up is taking 4-6 seconds before it even executes.  My ActiveRecord pool is at 25, and Sidekiq is running at 20 concurrency with 1 Unicorn process.

I benchmarked this worker in the rails console and the code is well under 2 seconds (it does a bit of heavy processing).  With this weird 4-6 seconds delay, New Relic is picking up transactions of this worker at 6 to 8 seconds execution.

I went through the perform method of the slow worker with NewRelic::Agent::MethodTracer, grouped blocks of code try to get a better idea of what could be so slow, but New Relic still shows the worker with 4 -6 seconds before it gets to any of the grouped blocks.

All the grouped blocks of code with tracers in the perform method are under 100 ms each.

I'm not sure what could be causing this 4 to 6 seconds pause for each worker -- while running the sidekiq jobs, memory usually hovers around 50 - 60% usage (2 digital ocean droplets at 1 gig), Disk I/O, and CPU don't ever hit over 60% the whole time.

My app is running on Rails 4.1.4, Ruby 2.0, Postgres, Unicorn, Nginx, and Redis

Answer (score 6):

You've tested single-threaded operation as really fast but when a bunch of jobs execute in parallel, it's really slow.  This is typical when jobs are fighting for exclusive access to a shared resource.

Comment: i just lowered the concurrency from 20 to 5 and indeed there is less of a pause. my app does require the workers to perform as fast as it can, since it sends back data to the user.  do you suggest running more sidekiq processes on multiple servers with a lower concurrency count (for instance, 4 sidekiq processes, with 5 concurrency each), versus my current set up (1 sidekiq process, 25 concurrency).  i figured this way i can lower the delay that processes get executed while still having around 20 jobs being worked on concurrently

Comment: Sounds like that would be best if you don't want to track down the underlying concurrency issue.

Answer (score 3):

Are you measuring just execution time with your profiler? We are also looking at the queuing time here. That is the most likely explanation for this difference. However, to really build an accurate picture of what is happening a lot more information is required.

If you would like more insight into your Sidekiq jobs, I recommend installing the Sidekiq plugin which you can find here: http://newrelic.com/plugins/steven-eksteen/131

If you have any further questions, please reach out to us at support.newrelic.com where we will have your account information on hand ready to assist you.

Comment: i installed this plugin and am monitoring the data, im not getting anything right now (sidekiq 3.0.2) but will contact support regarding this